# Timeout exception on a service bus triggered function when external api is taking more than 4 minutes ro rerurn response

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, restsharp

I have a service bus triggered function that is makikg a post request to an external api. The function is working correctly when the api responds in 2 or 3 minutes, but when the api responds in 6 minutes or more I am getting a timeout exception. The time to live of a function and  httpTimeoitMinutes is set to 10 minutes(meaning RestSharp client.Timeout and client.ReadWriteTimeout is set to 10 minutes), so that is not the reason of my timeout exception. I am using RestSharp as a http client library. Does anyone know what might be the problem and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try KeepAlive?  The connection is closing because the connection is idle.  KeepAlive sends a zero byte TCP message periodically so the channel is not idle  HTTP uses TCP for the transport layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can i set KeppAlive?

Comment: Not sure.  Confused about other posting with similar issue.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/best-practices/business-logic/set-keepalive-false-interacting-external-hosts-plugin#problematic-patterns

Answer (score 0):

is the request idempotent? If it is, I would simply re-enqueue the message and re-process it

Comment: The problem is that the external service finished its job successfully, so I can't re-enqueue the message and re-process it because that message is already processed, i am just not getting back the success status from the external service

Comment: that's why I asked if the request to the external service is idempotent. What happens if you re-issue it?